# Core Data NSPersistentStoreCoordinator Abort From Incoming Phone Call, SWIFT

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspersistentstore

I've been spending a lot of time making my Core Data model work efficiently for my iOS app in development. For the most part I have everything working smoothly, but I encountered a unique error loading my data the other day by mere chance. I had just started running my app on my iPhone for testing, and right as it started up and began to load data using Core Data, my sister called me. The timing was rather fortuitous because that interruption seemed to have called the `abort()` function from the `persistentStoreCoordinator` in the `AppDelegate`.

Here is the code I'm referring to:

```
lazy var persistentStoreCoordinator: NSPersistentStoreCoordinator = {
    // The persistent store coordinator for the application. This implementation creates and returns a coordinator, having added the store for the application to it. This property is optional since there are legitimate error conditions that could cause the creation of the store to fail.
    // Create the coordinator and store
    let coordinator = NSPersistentStoreCoordinator(managedObjectModel: self.managedObjectModel)
    let url = self.applicationDocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("DataModel.sqlite")
    var failureReason = "There was an error creating or loading the application's saved data."
    let mOptions = [NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption: true,
        NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption: true]
    do {
        try coordinator.addPersistentStoreWithType(NSSQLiteStoreType, configuration: nil, URL: url, options: mOptions)
    } catch {
        // Report any error we got.
        var dict = [String: AnyObject]()
        dict[NSLocalizedDescriptionKey] = "Failed to initialize the application's saved data"
        dict[NSLocalizedFailureReasonErrorKey] = failureReason

        dict[NSUnderlyingErrorKey] = error as NSError
        let wrappedError = NSError(domain: "YOUR_ERROR_DOMAIN", code: 9999, userInfo: dict)
        // Replace this with code to handle the error appropriately.
        // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
        NSLog("Unresolved error \(wrappedError), \(wrappedError.userInfo)")

        abort()  // THIS
    }

    return coordinator
}()
```

Obviously I see where Apple commented that the `abort()` function needs to only be used during development, and should be removed once in production, but I'm wondering if anybody can show me how to properly handle this type of error?

I'm not loading a massive amount of data, and I'm thinking all I would need to do in this instance would be to just re-start the loading process.

I guess all I am really asking, is once the error is caught, is there a simple way to tell it to retry, or do I have to manually go back to how I called the data fetch at the app launch?

Comment: You could try putting the `addPersistentStoreWithType` call into a `dispatch_async`, as per the sample code in the [Core Data Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH4-SW1).  It *might* avoid the issue.

Comment: This is repeatable? And you can trigger it while debugging? What's the exception message ad stack?

Comment: @Wain - I apologize for taking so long to respond to your comment. Anyways the issue seems totally random. It happened at first when I had an incoming call right as I was running my app on my phone through xCode, now it just happened to me again for no reason I can pin-point. The error essentially says "An error occurred during persistent store migration", and then "reason=Failed to replace destination database". Could this be from manipulating my Data Model? I have my options set as such: `NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption` and `NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption` set to true.

Comment: hey, did you get the reason why the crash was happening.. I am also getting crashes in same scenarios. I have 3 iphone devices to test, but crash is happening only in iphone 6S.

Answer (score 0):

You can retry, but **usually** there's no point. If adding the persistent store fails, there's **usually** no chance of loading it any more, because the data is corrupt or otherwise unreadable. The only remaining option is to delete the existing file, create a new one, and (when available) restore the data from whatever cloud services you might be using.

However you can try again if you think it might be worthwhile. Call `addPersistentStoreWithType` again, with the same arguments, and see if it works. Check the return value-- if it's not nil and if no error was thrown, you're good to go. Until you return from this lazy var initialization, you can keep calling that method as many times as necessary.

Comment: Thanks, I will try out your suggestion. I have all my user data backed up in the cloud using Apple's `CloudKit` which has worked really well for me thus far, the only reason I wanted to avoid going that route, is the user would be out of luck if they weren't getting cell service or wifi at the time. I'll try all options before going down that road. This problem is a pain to test, because I have to time the phone call perfectly.